# Is it possible to use SpringData-JPA with a hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am already using Hibernate 4 directly with a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and a `SessionFactory` in my code.

I would now like to include Spring-Data-JPA in my code.

But Spring-Data needs an `EntityManagerFactory` to work, which can be configured through a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Can these Beans `LocalSessionFactoryBean`  and `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` coexist in one Spring project?

(Or can one be adapted by the other?)
What is the best practice?

Comment: No. As the name already implies it works for JPA not for plain hibernate. Switch your logic around, configure a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/faq.html), Section C2 shows you to obtain a `SessionFactory` from an `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: thanks a lot. In my old config I have a "mappingLocations" with value "classpath:/app.hbm.xml" .would you know where to put this property on EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Try `mappingResources` not sure if that would take hbm files though.

Comment: just as a side note HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean seems to want its EnitymanagerFactory to be in package "org.hibernate.ejb" which seems to me like a Bug

Comment: It wants the `HibernateEntityManagerFactory` which is needed to get access to the underlying hibernate classes.

Comment: thanks a lot. Its a pitty that you did not answer this question as an "answer" so that I could give you credit fo the right solution

Answer (score 7):

Although they can coexists it will be problematic especially if you want to have them participate in the same transaction. However if you switch your logic around and configure a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` you can use the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` to get access to the underlying `SessionFactory`.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- Your properties here -->
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now you have both and can participate in the same transaction.

This solution is also documented in the Spring Data JPA reference guide in the [FAQ section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entitymanager;


public List<SpBooking> list() {
   // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
System.out.println("******************************");

// @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<SpBooking> listUser = (List<SpBooking>)((Session)entitymanager.getDelegate())
            .createCriteria(SpBooking.class)               
            .list();

    for (SpBooking i:listUser)
   System.out.println("------------------"+i.getBookingId());

    return listUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And as of JPA 2.1, EntityManagerFactory.unwrap(java.lang.Class) provides a nice approach, documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.html

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```